# Opening bigger version of picture in new window /w javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I've managed to get the picture to open the bigger version of the picture into a new window using this code:

```
<IMG SRC="pic_small.jpg" onClick="view();">

<script language="JavaScript">

function view() {
imgsrc = "pic_big.jpg";


viewwin = window.open(imgsrc,'viewwin', 'width=600,height=300');    
}
</script>
```

The problem I got now is that I got many more pictures on my webpage and I'd like to not have to write another function for every script but instead having one function for all the pictures. In other words I'd like to have a script that does the same thing as above, but works on all of these (modified if needed) HTML lines

```
<IMG SRC="pic1_small.jpg" onClick="view();">
<IMG SRC="pic2_small.jpg" onClick="view();">
<IMG SRC="pic3_small.jpg" onClick="view();">
<IMG SRC="pic4_small.jpg" onClick="view();">
```

I was also wondering if there is some way to make the window that opens the the same size as the big picture.

Comment: Maybe fancybox is the option: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ . Hope this helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your first question

```
<IMG SRC="pic_small.jpg" onClick="view(this);">

<script language="JavaScript">
   function view(img) {
      imgsrc = img.src.split("_")[0] + "_big.jpg";
      viewwin = window.open(imgsrc,'viewwin', 'width=600,height=300');    
   }
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

To your second question, [it can be done](http://www.sitepoint.com/resize-popup-fit-images-size/).

**UPDATE 2**

This depends on your image names keeping that same format. Alternatively, you could do this:

```
<img src="pic_small.jpg" onclick="view('pic_big.jpg')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
   function view(imgsrc) {
      viewwin = window.open(imgsrc,'viewwin', 'width=600,height=300'); 
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) The first one worked perfectly but I will explore the other one now as well as I will use the same name format as it seems now.

Answer (score 0):

Using a js library such as lightbox is a good option. It does more or less what you ask. See e.g. [Lightbox 2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

By including lightbox, in combination with jquery, in your html, you can create a list of images with  tags with a "rel" property of "lightbox". Lightbox will then automatically activate when you click the link surrounding the image. Here is an example.

```
<a href="images/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">image #1</a>
```

See more examples here in the "how to use" section in the aforementioned link

Comment: Please provide a more substantive answer to the OP, such as how one would use the lightbox code you suggested while keeping a similar code structure.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @JeffreySweeney, i have tried to accomodate as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library which almost de-facto library for JS.
Using it you can do something like that

```
$('img').click(function(){
  view($(this).attr('src'));
})


function view(small){
  var big = small.split("_")[0] + "_big.jpg";
  viewwin = window.open(imgsrc,'viewwin', 'width=600,height=300');    
}
```

This way all your images will have the same behavior

Comment: Note: You don't NEED to use JQuery to do this. In fact, it's probably unnecessary for something this trivial.