# How can I open an images in a new window by using its class name?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open images in new window but i cant figure out the JavaScript code!

HTML:

```
<img class="picture" onclick="expand()" src="bild1.jpg">
```

Javascript:

```
function expand()
{   
var bigImage = document.getElementByClassName('picture');

var source=bigImage.getAttribute('src');
window.open(source)             
}
```

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908022/open-image-in-new-window                                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595003/opening-bigger-version-of-picture-in-new-window-w-javascript

Comment: At least you need to know, how [`getElementsByClassName`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18481044/1169519) or at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName), works.

Comment: Look at your JavaScript error console. Read the error messages. They'll make it pretty clear where you've screwed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target attribute specifies where to open the linked document..

You can use your image inside an anchor element.

```
<a target="_blank" href="yourimage.jpg"><img class="picture" src="yourimage.jpg"></a>
```

You dont need JS code

Answer (score 0):

Add the `target="_blank"` attribute to your links to open them in new windows, no javascript needed.

Comment: um...`<img>` != `<a>`...of course it would be a solution to put the images in a link

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="bild1.jpg" target="_blank"><img class="picture"  src="bild1.jpg"></a>
```

Comment: he asked how to do it by class name ?

Comment: Really?? What is the need of that as we can do by a simple technique.